# Shutting down pygame without using the mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a basic tic-tac-toe game where I have 2 agents playing randomly. I want the game to run 10000's of times. I can do this at the moment but the instance only resets after I press the close button on the pygame window. Instead I want the window to either continually close and open again or have the window stay open constantly with a reset of the game board etc - both are fine. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random
import time
import sys

def get_position(mouseX, mouseY):
    if mouseX <= width/3:
        col = 0
    elif mouseX <= 2*width/3:
        col = 1
    else:
        col = 2

    if mouseY <= height/3:
        row = 0
    elif mouseY <= 2*height/3:
        row = 1
    else:
        row = 2

    return (row, col)
def show_board(input, board):
    input.blit(board, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

def initialise_board(input):
    background = pygame.Surface(input.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))
    pygame.draw.line(background, (0, 0, 0), (width / 3, 0), (width / 3, height), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(background, (0, 0, 0), (2 * width / 3, 0), (2 * width / 3, height), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(background, (0, 0, 0), (0, height / 3), (width, height / 3), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(background, (0, 0, 0), (0, 2 * height / 3), (width, 2 * height / 3), 2)
    input.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    return background

def check_board(row, col, array_board):
    if array_board[row][col] != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True


#def get_mouse():
#    (mouseX, mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
#    (row, col) = get_position(mouseX, mouseY)
#    return (row, col)

def check_win(array_board):
    global winner
    for row in range(3):
        if array_board[row][0] == array_board[row][1] == array_board[row][2] != 0:
            winner = array_board[row][0]
            pygame.draw.line(board, (0, 0, 0), (75, (row*round(height/3) + 150)), (825, (row*round(height/3) + 150)), 3)
            break
    for col in range(3):
        if array_board[0][col] == array_board[1][col] == array_board[2][col] != 0:
            winner = array_board[col][0]
            pygame.draw.line(board, (0, 0, 0), (col*round(width/3) + 150, 75), (col*round(width/3)+ 150, 825), 3)
            break

    if array_board[0][0] == array_board[1][1] == array_board[2][2] != 0:
        winner = array_board[0][0]
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0, 0, 0,), (75, 75), (825, 825), 3)
    if array_board[0][2] == array_board[1][1] == array_board[2][0] != 0:
        winner = array_board[0][2]
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0,0,0), (825, 75), (75, 825), 3)
    return winner

def click_board(array_board):
    global team
    (row, col) = get_position(random.randint(1,900), random.randint(1,900))

    centerX = (col * round(width/3)) + 150
    centerY = (row * round(height/3)) + 150
    if team == 2 and check_board(row, col, array_board):
        pygame.draw.circle(board, (0, 0, 0), np.round((centerX, centerY)), round(width/12), 2)
        team = 1
        array_board[row][col] = 2
    elif team == 1 and check_board(row, col, array_board):
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0,0,0), (centerX - width/15, centerY - height/15), (centerX + width/15, centerY + height/15), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0,0,0), (centerX + width/15, centerY - height/15), (centerX - width/15, centerY + height/15), 2)
        team = 2
        array_board[row][col] = 1


def game(array_board, board):
    global winner, xwins, owins
    winner = check_win(array_board)
    if winner == 0 and team == 1:
        message = "X's turn"
    elif winner == 0 and team == 2:
        message = "O's turn"
    elif winner != 0 and team == 2:
        message = "X wins!"
        xwins += 1
    elif winner != 0 and team == 1:
        message = "O wins!"
        owins += 1

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render(message, 1, (10,10,10))
    board.fill((250,250,250), (width/2 - 20, 50, width/2 + 20, 50))
    board.blit(text, (width/2,50))

xwins = 0
owins = 0

for i in range(10):
    pygame.init()
    width = 900
    height = 900
    input = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tic-Tac-Toe')
    array_board = np.zeros([3,3])
    winner = 0
    team = 1 #team 1 is X, team 2 is O
    board = initialise_board(input)



    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and winner == 0:
        if winner == 0:
            print(winner)
            game(array_board, board)
            show_board(input, board)
            check_win(array_board)
            click_board(array_board)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to write this as a GUI / PyGame application at all?  If it's just two agents playing each other, they don't need a GUI, it could have just been bit-swapping over a pipe.

Comment: Well I originally just wanted to make the game - then decided to do random agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 conditions which end the game:

- either the winner is set (`winner != 0`)
- or all the fields on the playground are occupied
  (`np.array(np.where(array_board == 0)).size == 0`)

All you have to do is to implement the *else* case in your application and reset all the game states and redraw the empty playground.
Additionally you can count the games and `break` the loop after 10000 games.
The `for`-loop (`for i in range(10):`) is not need any more.

```py
no_of_games = 0
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    
    end_of_game = winner != 0 or np.array(np.where(array_board == 0)).size == 0
    if not end_of_game:
        print(winner)
        game(array_board, board)
        show_board(input, board)
        check_win(array_board)
        click_board(array_board)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        array_board = np.zeros([3,3])
        team = 1
        winner = 0
        time.sleep(1)
        board = initialise_board(input)
        no_of_games += 1

    if no_of_games >= 10000:
        break

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```